# How to bring up the firmware console on a SunBlade 100

Tags: sun-blade, sparc64

I've got an old SunBlade 100 workstation that I'm trying to install OpenBSD on.  The first step in the process is to bring up the OpenFirmware prompt to select the boot medium, which you do by pressing <kbd>STOP</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

The computer didn't have a keyboard when I bought it, but I found one that will work.  However, it doesn't have a <kbd>STOP</kbd> key.  Is there another way of bringing up the prompt?

Comment: This is something of a test to see [what constitutes "retro"](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-constitutes-retro).  The SunBlade line was discontinued ten years ago, right on the suggested threshold.  If you vote to close this, please leave a comment here or in that thread.

Comment: Seems legit to me. But I'm of the opinion that anything running Forth automatically retro-izes what it touches.

Comment: (But, I get it if folks think this belongs over on StackOverflow instead.)

Comment: Does Sun support this at all? But I think this question is OK on retro because it involves non-standard (and I assume discontinued) hardware.

Comment: @jdv By that logic, even a G5 mac is retro...

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. Congrats! You solve the puzzle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only know these a little from messing about with OpenFirmware, but I did run across [this reference that says](http://www.finnie.org/text/computers/sunblade100/):

> One glaring omission by Sun is that you cannot enter OBP from the OS
>   using a regular USB keyboard. You can enter OBP from the serial
>   console using Ctrl-Break, and Sun keyboards can do Stop-A, but there
>   is no way to enter OBP from a non-Sun USB keyboard.

Which is something I didn't know. I think this implies you are going to have to beg, borrow, or steal a keyboard.

Or try to boot to the serial console.

---

I do not have a SunBlade around anymore to test, but I just ran across a hint that you can get to the OBP if you push the power button twice after the first beep. Apparently, this was an alternative for this exact situation.

Comment: Your question at the end should be a comment on the question, not in your answer.

Comment: Do follow-up if the power button trick works.

Comment: I can confirm that tapping the power button brings up the firmware prompt.  No idea how many presses are needed; I just kept hitting it until I heard the startup beep.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a custom USB keyboard, this ought to be possible with any microcontroller which implementes a full USB device, so long as you can find the relevant codes to generate - that would maybe be simpler than sourcing the right hardware.

Comment: Specifically the key code Sun uses for Stop on USB keyboards is `0x78` https://kentie.net/article/sunkbd/sun%20keys.txt -- Sun USB keyboards are USB HID keyboards and this key is part of the USB HID standard https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf#page=56